# verifying differential equation solution with sage

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, sagemath

I solved the linear ODE system of equations:
\begin{equation}
x' = \begin{pmatrix}3&0&4\\0&2&0\\0&0&-3\end{pmatrix}x
\end{equation}

Skipping the details I got the following eigenpairs:

\begin{align}
\lambda_0=3, x_0=\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}&\\
\lambda_1=2, x_1=\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}&\\
\lambda_2=-3, x_2=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{2}{3}\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}&
\end{align}
Thus the general solution is:
\begin{equation}
x(t) = c_1e^{3t}\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix} + c_2e^{2t}\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}+c_3e^{-3t}\begin{pmatrix}\frac{2}{3}\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
Here is what I got from sage:

```
sage: t = var('t') 
sage: x = function('x', t)
sage: y = function('y', t)
sage: z = function('z', t)
sage: de1 = diff(x, t) -3*x -4*z == 0
sage: de2 = diff(y, t) -2*y == 0                                            
sage: de3 = diff(z, t) +3*z == 0                                            
sage: desolve_system([de1, de2, de3], [x, y, z])                            
[x(t) == 1/3*(3*x(0) + 2*z(0))*e^(3*t) - 2/3*e^(-3*t)*z(0),                 
 y(t) == e^(2*t),                                                           
 z(t) == e^(-3*t)*z(0)]
```

So my solution looks fine in terms of $y(t)$ and $z(t)$ but my $x(t)$ is different in the coefficient of $e^{3t}$

**Why does sage give a different answer?**

Specifically:

1. Did I solve the system incorrectly?
2. Did sage choose different eigenvectors?
3. Is sage only giving me a nicer scaling of the eigenvectors?

All help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I have done that and could do that but the idea is to use sage to become more efficient. Especially when the differential equations get a lot uglier, I could save a lot of time learning how to solve them in sage and look at their plots and so forth.

Comment: I am also a little confused with the sage output for $x(t)$ as there is a constant term and I do not have that.

Comment: Looks good, but could you clarify what you mean by "if you reduce all of their constants to a single constant then you basically get the same thing"

Comment: Please see my updates, very strange with Sage (I do not trust it as I do not understand why it works that way). Maxima did just fine with eigenvalues/eigenvectors (included a link to image). Regards

Comment: This is really confusing then. A lot of the documentation for Sage says that it interfaces with Maxima...

Comment: It shouldn't be confusing. Sage is made up of dozens of programs. Enter the matrix as you show it and you'll see it gives a wrong eigenvalue. It is a large program and programs have bugs, I used two different approaches to validate my result, including manually doing it, so am very confident in those results.

Comment: Thanks for helping me verify!

Comment: You are very welcome! You are doing great by coming up with solutions and then experimenting with CAS programs and asking questions - that is excellent. I would try more than one program like online Maxima too, just to have two opinions in addition to your manual approach! Hope you were able to work through this. Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, we have:

$$x' = \begin{bmatrix}3&0&4\\0&2&0\\0&0&-3\end{bmatrix}x$$

The CP is: $-\lambda^3+2 \lambda^2+9 \lambda-18 \rightarrow \lambda_1 = -3 , \lambda_2 =3 , \lambda_3 = 2$.

We have three distinct and real eigenvalues, so we form $[A-\lambda I] v_i = 0$ to find the eigenvectors and get the following eigenvalue/eigenvector pairs:

- For $\lambda_1 = -3$, the RREF gives us:

$c = 3, b= 0 , a = -(2/3) c = -2 \rightarrow v_1 = (-2,0,3)$ (note, c is a free variable)

- For $\lambda_2 = 3$, the RREF gives us:

$c = 0, b= 0 , a = 1 \rightarrow v_2 = (1,0,0)$ (note, a is a free variable)

- For $\lambda_3 = 2$, the RREF gives us:

$a = 0, c = 0, b = 1 \rightarrow v_3 = (0,1,0)$ (note, b is a free variable)

Summarizing these, we have:

- $\lambda_1 = -3, ~v_1 = (-2, 0, 3)$
- $\lambda_2 = 3, ~v_2 = (1, 0, 0)$
- $\lambda_3 = 2, ~v_3 = (0, 1, 0)$

The solution is then given by:

$$x(t) = c_1 e^{\lambda_1 t}v_1  + c_2 e^{\lambda_2 t}v_2  + c_3 e^{\lambda_3 t} v_3 = c_1 e^{-3t}\begin{bmatrix}-2\\0\\3\end{bmatrix} + c_2e^{3t} \begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix} + c_3e^{2t}\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}$$

If we compare this to your solution, you note that for my first vector, I chose $c=3$, where you chose $1$, hence these are actually the same (actually, you lost a negative sign - please check that)!

If we write out the solution for this, we get:

$$x(t) = \begin{bmatrix}x(t)\\y(t)\\z(t)\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} - 2c_1 e^{-3t}+c_2e^{3t} \\ c_3 e^{2t}\\ 3c_1e^{-3t}\end{bmatrix}$$

First question, why are the variables all negated in the Sage approach? That changes things. The eigenvalues are the same, but the eigenvectors are swapped around. Can you try it with the same signs as the matrix has?

It also looks like they are using some other algorithm to find these, but if you reduce all of their constants to a single constant, it is basically the same. It is odd that they chose $c_3 = 1$, but there is likely a reason for that.

Let me clarify what I am saying here. For their solution, we can equate their constants (make sure I did not make a silly algebra error here) to the ones we used as:

- $c_1 = \dfrac{z(0)}{3}, c_2 = \dfrac{1}{3}(3 x(0) + 2 z(0)), c_3 = 1$.

These are totally arbitrary, but with that change, you can see we are talking the same thing. Whatever internal algorithm they are using chooses things in that form.

**Update**

I ran the script using the online version of Sage with the same variables and signs as the matrix $A$, and the result (I MathJax'ed it) is:

- $x(t) = \dfrac{1}{3}(3 x(0) + 2 z(0))e^{-3t} - \frac{2}{3}e^{3t}z(0)$
- $y(t) = e^{-2t}y(0)$
- $z(t) = e^{3t}z(0)$

Which has the wrong sign for an eigenvalue (online version), maybe for all three as it is hard to tell!

I tried the online Maxima and here is the [*result*](http://maxima-online.org/plot.html?g=i976675677&t=img&db=r1963407777), just like my eigenvalues/eigenvectors (note the sign and fraction on one of them).

So, why does Sage require users to change all of the signs of the matrix? Regardless, changing the signs does produce the correct eigenvalues and the constants as shown above and through the simple transformation, it is the same result I derived.

Comment: Excellent! $\;\oplus^+$

Comment: It's nice that you were able to confirm the OP's work! What unnecessary confusion sage online seems to have created!